# How to select last day of the month SQL if the are no entries for that month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following entries,

| ID | date | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2014-05-18' | 5 |
| 1 | '2014-06-19' | 4 |
| 1 | '2014-07-20' | 25 |
| 2 | '2014-05-20' | 7 |
| 3 | '2014-05-18' | 4 |
| 3 | '2014-06-20' | 1 |
| 4 | '2014-05-18' | 6 |

I am trying to extract the values between two dates in this case it happens to be.
2014-05-18 to 2014-07-20. The  select output should have an entry for every month, if any of the month is not having a value it should default to zero for that month and that date should be the last day of that particular month.

The expected output is

| ID | date | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2014-05-18' | 5 |
| 1 | '2014-06-19' | 4 |
| 1 | '2014-07-20' | 25 |
| 2 | '2014-05-20' | 7 |
| 2 | '2014-06-30' | 0 |
| 2 | '2014-07-31' | 0 |
| 3 | '2014-05-18' | 4 |
| 3 | '2014-06-20' | 1 |
| 3 | '2014-07-31' | 0 |
| 4 | '2014-05-18' | 6 |
| 4 | '2014-06-30' | 0 |
| 4 | '2014-07-31' | 0 |

I have tried using this but It give the list for all the days of that month, But I am interested only in the Last day of the month.

```
    ;WITH n AS
    (
      SELECT n = 0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1 FROM n
      WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, '20140518', '20140720')
    ),
    range AS
    (
      SELECT [date] = DATEADD(DAY, n,'20140518') FROM n
    ),
    IDs AS
    (
      SELECT ID 
        FROM dbo.MyTable AS t
        INNER JOIN range
        ON t.[date] = range.[date]
        GROUP BY ID
    )
    SELECT 
      IDs.ID,
      range.[date],
      Frequency = COALESCE(t.Frequency, 0)
    FROM range CROSS JOIN IDs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MyTable AS t
    ON t.[date] = range.date 
    AND IDs.ID = t.ID;
```

Comment: Side note: I suggest using a Tally over an rCTE if you have more than a handful of rows, as it's significantly faster. If you're producing 100's of dates, it also doesn't suffer the max recursion issue.

Comment: I am unable to get rod of the additional dates which I am getting  with the above query. I believe my approach itself is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting variation on the "filling in the blanks" type of query.  The difference is that you want to keep the original rows if they match, but create a new one for months that do not.

You can approach this by:

- Generating a range with one row per month.
- Cross joining to generate a row for each id and each month.
- Joining back to the original data to get any rows that already exist.

This looks like:

```
WITH months AS (
      SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR('20140518'), MONTH('20140518'), 1) as mon
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, mon)
      FROM months
      WHERE mon < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR('20140720'), MONTH('20140720'), 1)
    )
SELECT i.id,
       COALESCE(t.date, EOMONTH(m.mon)),
       COALESCE(t.frequency, 0)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM dbo.MyTable) i CROSS JOIN
     months m LEFT JOIN
     dbo.MyTable t
     ON t.id = i.id AND
        t.date >= m.mon AND
        t.date < DATEADD(month, 1, m.mon);
```

Note that you can generate the dates you want directly in a recursive CTE.  There is no need to generate numbers first.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might be better off with generating dates for the month start and end dates, and then joining from that to your table. Then you can use an `ISNULL` on the `[date]` column from your table and return the upper boundary date instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            [date] date,
                            Frequency int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,'20140518',5),
      (1,'20140619',4),
      (1,'20140720',25),
      (2,'20140520',7),
      (3,'20140518',4),
      (3,'20140620',1),
      (4,'20140518',6);
GO

DECLARE @DateStart date = '20140518',
        @DateEnd date = '20140720';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,@DateStart,@DateEnd)+1) --Limits to the number of months you need
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2), --Max 100 months, if you need more month add more cross joins
Months AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,@DateStart),-1)) AS MonthStart,
           EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,@DateStart)) AS MonthEnd
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT I.ID,
       ISNULL(YT.[date],M.MonthEnd) AS [Date],
       ISNULL(YT.Frequency,0) AS Frequency
FROM Months M
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM dbo.YourTable) I
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON I.ID = YT.ID
                               AND YT.[date] BETWEEN M.MonthStart AND M.MonthEnd
                               AND YT.[date] BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
ORDER BY ID,
         [Date];

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Note I also switch to a Tally here, instead of a rCTE, as (as the name suggests) an rCTE is recursive where as a Tally is not; thus for large data sets will be (far) more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You've done some good work. Now just filter out the non-last days, probably in your `range` cte:

```
...
range AS
    (
        SELECT [date] = q.date
        FROM n
        cross apply( select DATEADD(DAY, n,'20140518') as date) as q
        where datepart(day,dateadd(day,1,q.date))=1
    ),
...
```

This just takes the [date] you calculated, and makes sure the next day is the first of month.

Comment: I have tried using to filter the date values using this command but it give me bank output. I dont get any output in return. I am not sure what are the values what are getting filtered..